# make a variable inside a function accessible to other functions?

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

inside of a function i have a $connection var what obviously stores my connection to mysql,
how can i call that var from inside other functions to save me having to paste the $connection var inside of every function that requires this var?

i have tried  global to no avail.

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the old `global` keyword.

```
function a() {
   global $connection;
}
```

Or you could throw it in `$GLOBALS` (this will help you get it out of the function defined it in).

Neither of them are too pretty.

Or you could pass in the `$connection` as an argument.

The most common way of dealing with a database connection is to have its creation handled by a singleton pattern, or have a base class with OO that has a `$this->db` available, that all your other classes can inherit from.

Comment: +1 Although it's funny you mention the singleton pattern, because it is very similar to a global variable... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the connection as a parameter to the functions that need it. It keeps your code clean and re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a class and make the connection a class variable. You will just use `$this->connection` every time you need this, but this is not really a solution if you already have a lot of code written in a lot of files.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside the function, then make it accessible inside each function you need it by using the global keyword.

```
$globalName = "Zoe";

function sayHello() {
  $localName = "Harry";
  echo "Hello, $localName!";

  global $globalName;
  echo "Hello, $globalName!";
}

sayHello();
```

stolen from http://www.elated.com/articles/php-variable-scope-all-you-need-to-know/